# Sound on speakers, but headphones don't work on Asus X553M [Ubuntu 14.04.1]

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm having a big problem with my headphones on partner's notebook: it's running on dual boot (Win10 and Ubuntu 14.04.1) and although sound works fine on speaker, it doesn't work on headphones.

I've installed pulseaudio and tried a couple of solutions here, none of them worked.

It detects the headphone being connected and I can "see" the audio being played on pulseaudio, but no sound comes from it - of course, it's not muted on alsamixer.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Windows10 fastboot can be faulty, try to disabled it:  http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/